# Getting started with Spring + BlazeDS integration. Hello World wanted

Tags: java, spring, blazeds

I'm trying to get my hands a small Spring + BlazeDS integration "Hello World"-ish type of sample/tutorial to see the basic, minimum configuration required for using the Spring & BlazeDS integration available from http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex

The download I got came with all these test drive samples, but I can't make freakin' heads or tails about whats going on here. All I want, is a simple Hello World app to get a bare bones project up in Eclipse so I can see what is supposed to go where...

I just need one Bean, with one Service like HelloWorld.sayHi(String name);

Can anyone offer any valuable links/advice on this topic?